# Attribute error:class has no object and TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

Tags: python

I am basically trying to initialize the class with some set of variables. For `self.dim_max` I try to compute the permutation and binarization of a train_data which is nothing but a matrix of 5232 x 23 x 23.

1. I have no issues with the logic, but am getting an error:

```
for k in np.arange(0, self.max[i] + self.step, self.step):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

Here's the code:

```
Class Model(Object):    

     def __init__(self, n_inpt, n_hiddens, n_output, train_data,
                 hidden_transfers, out_transfer, loss,
                 imp_weight=False,
                 optimizer='adam',
                 batch_size=None,
                 max_iter=1000, verbose=False):

        self.dim_max = self.transformedData(train_data)
        self.n_inpt = self.dim_max.shape[1]
        self.n_hiddens = n_hiddens
        self.n_output = n_output
        self.hidden_transfers = hidden_transfers
        self.out_transfer = out_transfer
        self.loss_ident = loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.imp_weight = imp_weight

        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.verbose = verbose

        self.f_predict = None

        self._init_exprs()


    def transformedData(self, traindata):
        E = traindata
        self.step = 1.0
        self.noise = 1.0
        self.triuind = (np.arange(23)[:, np.newaxis] <= np.arange(23)[np.newaxis, :]).flatten()
        self.max = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            self.max = np.maximum(max, self.realize(E).max(axis=0))
        X = self.expand(self.realize(E))
        return X

    def realize(self, X):
        def _realize_(x):
            inds = np.argsort(-(x**2).sum(axis=0)**.5 + np.random.normal(0, self.noise, x[0].shape))
            x = x[inds, :][:, inds] * 1
            x = x.flatten()[self.triuind]
            return x
        return np.array([_realize_(z) for z in X])

    def expand(self, X):
        Xexp = []
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            for k in np.arange(0, self.max[i] + self.step, self.step):
                Xexp += [np.tanh((X[:, i] - k) / self.step)]
        return np.array(Xexp).T
```

2. Then for the same block of code I tried like changing the `def transformedData(self, traindata):` as follows. But for this am getting an error like

```
in _realize_
    inds = np.argsort(-(x**2).sum(axis=0)**.5 + np.random.normal(0, self.noise, x[0].shape))
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'noise'
```

Here's the code for this:

```
Class Model(Object):    

     def __init__(self, n_inpt, n_hiddens, n_output, train_data,
                 hidden_transfers, out_transfer, loss,
                 imp_weight=False,
                 optimizer='adam',
                 batch_size=None,
                 max_iter=1000, verbose=False):

        self.dim_max = self.transformedData(train_data)
        self.n_inpt = self.dim_max.shape[1]
        self.n_hiddens = n_hiddens
        self.n_output = n_output
        self.hidden_transfers = hidden_transfers
        self.out_transfer = out_transfer
        self.loss_ident = loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.imp_weight = imp_weight

        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.verbose = verbose

        self.f_predict = None

        self._init_exprs()
        self.step = 1.0
        self.noise = 1.0
        self.triuind = (np.arange(23)[:, np.newaxis] <= np.arange(23)[np.newaxis, :]).flatten()
        self.max = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            self.max = np.maximum(max, self.realize(E).max(axis=0))   

    def transformedData(self, traindata):
        E = traindata
        X = self.expand(self.realize(E))
        return X

   def realize(self, X):
       **same as above**

   def expand(self, X):
      **same as above**
```

Can someone help me in solving these issues ?

Comment: where are you getting these errors, in which lines?

Comment: The error message should be telling you the line number. Please include that information in your question.

Comment: I have updated the error message

Comment: your code can't be run. It seems to depend on a global variable named `np`.

Comment: np is nothing but import numpy as np

Answer (score 0):

The error message `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'` means exactly what it says. You are trying to add a floating point number and a built-function (*not* the result of a function, but the *actual* function).

This either means you have a typo (ie: forgot to add `()` when calling a function), or you're making an assumption that a variable contains a value when it is actually a reference to a built-in function.

The error message `AttributeError: 'Mlp' object has no attribute 'noise'` also means literally that. You have an object named `Mlp` and you're trying to access the `noise` attribute, but it doesn't have a `noise` attribute.

The first step in resolving these issues is to validate your own assumptions. The simplest thing to do is add a print statement immediately before the lines causing the error, so you can see what the values are that are being used in the failing code.

Comment: I tried float(self.max[i]) + self.step, but it's not working

Comment: Sorry your response is more general, could you be more specific.

Comment: @prime: no, because your code isn't runable as posted. When I try to fix some of the issues, I get different errors than you report. Do what I suggested in my answer - validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first error is caused by these lines:

```
for _ in range(10):
    self.max = np.maximum(max, self.realize(E).max(axis=0))
```

The `max` being passed to you `np.maximum` call is presumably the builtin `max` function, rather than the number `self.max` which I think you had intended to use. In Python 2, non-numeric objects can always be compared with other classes of objects, though the result is arbitrary (but consistent).

Your second error has to do with the order you're setting attributes in `__init__`. You're setting `self.noise` pretty late in the function. Before you do so, you call `self.transformdData`, which calls `self.realize`, which tries to access `self.noise`, which doesn't exist yet. If you reorder your assignments, you should avoid this error.

Comment: So do you suggest me to use different variable name for max ?

Comment: The solution for the second question was helpful.

Comment: I think you need `self.max` instead of just `max`. Plain `max` is the builtin function that's causing your error message. `self.max` is initially `0`, which should work just fine when you add a float to it.